# python jdbc connection RuntimeError: Unable to load DLL

Tags: java, python, jpype, jaydebeapi

I am trying to use jaydebeapi to connect to Teradata DB but when i run my code, it gives me this error:

```
RuntimeError: Unable to load DLL
 [/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Libraries/libjvm.dylib], error = dlopen(/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Libraries/libjvm.dylib, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
        /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Libraries/libjvm.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture at native/common/include/jp_platform_linux.h:45
```

i then tried to see if its due to a missing `libjvm.dylib` or if it in the wrong location.
i typed in terminal:

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7
```

Checked if libjvm was in the correct location. Output looked right:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Libraries/libjvm.dylib
```

Is this my Java issue or a Jpype issue?

Answer (score 0):

In the end, it was a JAVA issue. Just had to reboot the JVM.